# Resolving multiple promises for fetching data from firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, async-await

I have the following code, I want to fetch data from two collections of firestore,the first element of each collection data. What reason data is not being returned ?

```
const myFunction = async () => {
  const usersData = await db.collection("users").get()
  const productsData = await db.collection("products").get()
  return [usersData[0], productsData[0]]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this solution

```js
 const myFunction = async () => {
    const users =
      (await db.collection("users").get()).docs.map((each) => each.data()) || [];
    const products =
      (await db.collection("products").get()).docs.map((each) => each.data()) ||
      [];
    // making sure the solution doesn't return undefined or null
    return [users?.[0] ?? {}, products?.[0] ?? {}];
};
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: Thanks this works if I use two await, but this will be fine I guess.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `get()` on a [CollectionReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference#limit) that'll fetch all the N documents present in that collection and you'll be charged for N reads. Instead, you should be using a query with limit 1 that'll only fetch the first document ordered by the constraints that you specify as shown below:

```
const myFunction = async () => {
  const [usersData, productsData] = await Promise.all([
    db.collection("users").limit(1).get(),
    db.collection("products").limit(1).get()
  ])

  return [usersData.docs[0]?.data(), productsData.docs[0]?.data()]
}
```

The queries above will only cost 2 reads (1 from each collection).